# Math in Jquery failure

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so the problem is quite simple, and Im not sure how to resolve it.

There are 2 input boxes from which Im getting the results and if I enter for example inside box 1: 5 and in the box 2: 5 it should give me 10 but it tells me its 55.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dugme").click(function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("itemSelected");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        var val1 = $("#Broj1").val();
        var val2 = $("#Broj2").val();


        var valEnd

        if(strUser = "saberi") {
            valEnd = val1+val2;
            alert(valEnd);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Input element values are always strings. You can use the unary `+` operator to force the strings to be interpreted as numbers: `+val1 + +val2`

Answer (score 1):

The values you are adding together are strings, so they are being concatenated. You'll need to parse those values to int to get this working. Something like...

```
var val1 = parseInt($("$Broj1").val());
```

Would do the trick...

Also your `if` statement is actually an assignment and not a comparison. It should look like

```
if(strUser === "saberi")
```

Comment: Yes but im not getting the alert box now... Maybe problem with my if's?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that but you are basically assigning the value "saberi" to the strUser variable in the if.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! That just resolved it! :)